# Live clock javascript starts from my custom time

Tags: javascript, ajax, time, clock

I was trying to create a live/dynamic clock is based on my custom time instead of system time.

There are many scripts, but I couldn't find the clock starts from my custom time.

Here is an example that I'm trying to modify. The problem is the seconds doesn't change, and it looks like I need to use ajax. Is there any way to do it without ajax? If not, help me to do it using ajax!!! The reason I don't like ajax method is that another page should be called and refreshed, so it will eat server ram.

ex)
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut2.shtml

Before:

```
<script> 
function show(){ 
var Digital=new Date() 
var hours=Digital.getHours() 
var minutes=Digital.getMinutes() 
var seconds=Digital.getSeconds() 
... 
...
```

After:

```
<script> 
function show(){ 
var Digital=new Date() 
var hours=<?php echo $hr; ?>; 
var minutes=<?php echo $min; ?>; 
var seconds=<?php echo $sec; ?>; 
... 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your clock isn't moving is because it's using the hours, minutes and seconds values set by the server when the page was originally rendered, as opposed to a fresh new `Date()` instance created each time `show()` is called.  You'll want to take advantage of JavaScript's built in `Date` object to create an accurate clock, as `setTimeout` isn't known for its accuracy and building your own clock would be a hassle (imaging having to worry about leaps years and daylight savings and stuff!).

What I'd recommend is to adjust the clock value each time `show()` is called using the *difference* between your *custom* time and the *real* time.  For example, if your custom time is 30 minutes behind the real time, you can call:

```
function show() {
   var Digital=new Date();
   Digital.setMinutes(Digital.getMinutes() - 30); // Rewind 30 minutes
   var hours=Digital.getHours()
   var minutes=Digital.getMinutes()
   var seconds=Digital.getSeconds()
   // ..
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz3U6/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.. Good point!!
However, hr and sec doesn't work..

ex)
function show(){
var Digital=new Date();
Digital.getSeconds(Digital.getSeconds() - 30); // Rewind 30 sec
var hours=Digital.getHours()

Comment: You want `setSeconds`.  `Digital.setSeconds(Digital.getSeconds() - 30);`

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to check the Mark as Answer box if you're so inclined.